# MYSQL MULTIPLE COUNT

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have 2 tables, #1 called TESTS, #2 RESULTS

```
#1 TESTS (TESTID, LEVELID)
#2 RESULTS (USERID, TESTID, SCORE)
```

I would like to get TWO COUNTS, #1 total tests for a level, and #2, total tests from RESULTS where score = 100 GROUP BY LEVELID

I have 15 levels, so I basically want to get results something like this

```
Level 1 - 15 tests, 3 perfect
Level 2 - 25 tests, 5 perfect
....
....
Level 15 - 75 tests, 8 perfect
```

How can I do this using 1 SQL statement and is that the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a well-posed question and I think the right one to ask in this situation.

First do a join for tests and results:

```
 SELECT
    t.level,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.score = 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS perfectcount
 FROM tests t
 JOIN results r
    ON t.testid = r.testid
 GROUP BY t.testid
```

Then extend it with another join on tests to get the level sum:

```
 SELECT t.level,
     COUNT(*) AS levelcount,
     t0.perfectcount
 FROM tests AS t
 JOIN {
     SELECT
        t.level,
        SUM(CASE WHEN r.score = 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS perfectcount
     FROM tests t
     JOIN results r
        ON t.testid = r.testid
     GROUP BY t.testid
) AS t0
    ON t.level = t0.level
GROUP BY t.level
```

Comment: Excellent answer, just missing WHERE userID = currentUSERID (Where would be the best place for that?).  Also what happened to the last answer that was up?  Was it incorrect?  It was also well written.

Comment: Ok, right direction, things i noticed so far. 1) Either gives a 1 or 0 for PERFECT score results and doesnt sum it up.  2) the total tests seem to be multiplied by the # of tests found in the results area...not sure why that is. 3) need to compare userID so its not ALL tests by all users.

Comment: OK #1 and #2 were fixed by changing GROUP BY t.testid to GROUP BY t.level, still trying to figure out where to put user ID :)

Comment: Fixed #3 by adding AND UserID = 'userIDVar' to SUM(CASE WHEN r.score = 100 AND r.UserID = 'userIDVar' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 'Level '+TestID+' - '+Count(*)+' tests, '+SUM(CASE WHEN Score = 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )+' perfect'
FROM Results
GROUP BY TestID
```

Syntax might be different in mysql and you might need `cast(TestID as varchar)`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think just "abc"+"zxc" won't work in MySQL, so better use `CONCAT('Level ', LEVELID, ...)` instead. And I think `TESTID` isn't actually level id, so you'll need to join TESTS table instead: `'Level ', LEVELID, '-', COUNT(r.TESTID), ' tests'... FROM RESULTS r INNER JOIN TESTS t ON (t.TESTID = r.TESTID) GROUP BY t.LEVELID;`

Comment: For the Level 1 - 15 tests, 3 perfect LINE, that was an example of the data i would like to be stored in a datatable.  I can modify its out display easily later taking data from that table.   For now I tried   qString = "SELECT tTests.cLevelID, COUNT(*) FROM tTests, tResults WHERE tResults.cUserID =" + gUID + " AND tResults.cTestID = tTests.cTestID AND tResults.cScore = 100 AND tTests.cLevelID > 0 GROUP BY tTests.cLevelID ORDER BY tTests.cLevelID ASC";  BUT I ONLY get results for when there are tests in results area.  I wanna be able to get results even when there are ZERO perect 100 tests :)

Comment: Just take out `tResults.cScore = 100` in the where clause